# wp-async-task don't fire run_action method

Tags: php, asynchronous, wordpress, background-process

I have to work with the techcrunch [wp-async-task](https://github.com/techcrunch/wp-async-task) to run a synchronization task in background in my **wordpress plugin**.

So to test, at the bottom of the main file I have :

```
//top of the php file
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/WP_Async_Task.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/class/my_api_status.class.php');
define('API_URL', '...');

/* ... */

// At the bottom of the file
function my_api_status($api_url)
{
  sleep(5);
  $r = wp_safe_remote_get($api_url);
  if (!is_wp_error($r)) {
    $body = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($r));
    if (isset($body->success)) {
      return;
    }
  }
}
add_action('wp_async_api_status', 'my_api_status');

function my_init_api_status()
{
  new ApiStatusTask();
  do_action('api_status', constant('API_URL'));
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'my_init_api_status');
```

And api status task class

```
class ApiStatusTask extends WP_Async_Task {

  protected $action = 'api_status';

  /**
   * Prepare data for the asynchronous request
   * @throws Exception If for any reason the request should not happen
   * @param array $data An array of data sent to the hook
   * @return array
   */
  protected function prepare_data( $data ) {
    return array(
      'api_url' => $data[0]
    );
  }

  /**
   * Run the async task action
   */
  protected function run_action() {
    if(isset($_POST['api_url'])){
      do_action("wp_async_$this->action", $_POST['api_url']);
    }
  }

}
```

The function `prepare_data` is correctly called by `launch`and after that `launch_on_shutdown` is also correctly called and finally `wp_remote_post` is called at the end of `launch_on_shutdown` with `admin-post.php`.
But the function `run_action` is never called ... and so the `my_api_status` in the main file.

What it possibly go wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will put a complete example of a plugin here soon. But for now, I found my problem :

```
// In the `launch_on_shutdown` method of `WP_Async_Task` class

public function launch_on_shutdown() {
  GcLogger::getLogger()->debug('WP_Async_Task::launch_on_shutdown');
  if ( ! empty( $this->_body_data ) ) {
    $cookies = array();
    foreach ( $_COOKIE as $name => $value ) {
      $cookies[] = "$name=" . urlencode( is_array( $value ) ? serialize( $value ) : $value );
    }

    $request_args = array(
        'timeout'   => 0.01,
        'blocking'  => false,
        'sslverify' => false, //apply_filters( 'https_local_ssl_verify', true ),
        'body'      => $this->_body_data,
        'headers'   => array(
            'cookie' => implode( '; ', $cookies ),
        ),
    );

    $url = admin_url( 'admin-post.php' );
    GcLogger::getLogger()->debug('WP_Async_Task::launch_on_shutdown wp_remote_post');
    wp_remote_post( $url, $request_args );
  }
}
```

The **sslverify** option failed in my local environment. I just had to put it on false if we are not in production.

With this option set, the `run_action` is correctly trigger.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for posting this! I tried to run this similar setup on my Wordpress v4.7.5. I had setup the custom class which extends WP_Async_Task  class in my theme functions.php file. But this is not working, even when setting the sslverify in the in the `launch_on_shutdown` method of `WP_Async_Task` class.

Comment: Do you know if the Techcrunch plugin and this method will work in Wordpress v4.7.5. Been struggling to get this plugin working with a hook, even the wp_async_save_post hook.